# Android debugging asking for an activity to be killed (simulating low memory)

Tags: android, eclipse

To rigorously debug an android application (using Eclipse) I would like to have android kill a paused activity (paused because another activity is in the foreground). In this case there is no onStop method so it can be killed now that onPause has run, as if in a very low on memory scenario. It would also be nice to know if Eclipse can force the kill to take place after onStop.

Just in case it makes things more complicated, the background activity that I would like zapped is the same class as the foreground activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same class" - is it literally an instance of the same Java Activity Class?  If so beware that killing happens only at process granularity, and everything in an apk will ordinarily share a process.

Comment: Yes, the foreground and paused activities are both instances of exactly the same subclass of PreferenceActivity (only used on pre Honeycomb devices). Are you saying that android would never kill the paused activity?

Comment: You may want to use logging or `ps` to verify if they are in the same process, but *killing* can only happen at the process level.  Android may be able to *destroy* an unneeded activity to reclaim some of the resources without killing its process (and any other activities contained within), but I don't know that it will do so.  For testing an emulator might be interesting as you could restrict the system memory, or start up another process that gobbles memory and using the fact that adb shell is root there protect it with custom oom killer values.